# Using MetaPivot GoodData Transformer to pivot part of the csv file columns

Tags: gooddata

I have a csv file that I would like to pivot part of its columns to rows.

I guess I should use the MetaPivot Transformer, however, since I just want to pivot **part** of the file, I don't know how to do it.

Does anyone know?

If it is not possible through MetaPivot, what is the alternative? 
I've already tried to break the file into 2 flows, but in the end I have to join them by recordNo, which I don't know how to get from my data.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For this case use [Normalizer](http://doc.cloveretl.com/documentation/UserGuide/index.jsp?topic=/com.cloveretl.gui.docs/docs/normalizer.html).